# Exercício URI 1005: Correção de código C (média simples)

Tags: c

**PERGUNTA:** Quando comitei meu código no URI ele retornou "*Wrong answer (60%)"*. Abaixo estão a descrição do exercício e o código inserido.

O que está faltando? Qual código?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
double A, B, MEDIA;

do{
      scanf("%lf", &A);

}while(A<0 || A>10);

do{
      scanf("%lf", &B);

}while(B<0 || B>10);


MEDIA=(A+B)/2;

printf("MEDIA = %.5lf\n", MEDIA);
```

Answer (score 2):

O principal erro no seu código é você está fazendo uma média simples e neste caso tem de ser ponderada pelo menos acho eu, porque eles dão pesos para as notas. Eu fiz um código,testei os exemplos e funcionou na perfeição. Se você não entendeu algo pergunte.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   double nota_A,nota_B,media;

   do
   {
       printf("\nDigite a nota A (0 a 10.0): ");
       scanf("%lf",&nota_A);

       if(nota_A < 0 || nota_A > 10.0)
           printf("Nota inválida tente novamente\n");

   }while(nota_A < 0 || nota_A > 10.0);

   do
   {
       printf("\nDigite a nota B (0 a 10.0): ");
       scanf("%lf",&nota_B);

       if(nota_B < 0 || nota_B > 10.0)
          printf("Nota inválida tente novamente\n");

   }while(nota_B < 0 || nota_B > 10.0);

   media = ((nota_A*3.5)+(nota_B*7.5))/(3.5+7.5); // Aqui é uma media ponderada e não uma media simples devido às notas terem pesos

   printf("\nA média das notas A e B é de %.5lf",media); // coloquei %.5lf porque eles pedem 5 casas decimais 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente. Nem acredito que foi só falta de atenção!           Muito obrigada e desculpe-me pela pergunta, deveria ter revisado meu código com o enunciado, mas li somente uma vez . De qualquer forma, obrigada!